# How to draw arrow between ellipses

Tags: svg, geometry, ellipse

I'm trying to programmatically draw an arrow from one ellipse to another, like below. How do I calculate where on ellipse B's edge the arrow needs to point? Or is there an easier way to do this in SVG? I am given the `x` and `y` coordinates of each ellipse along with their horizontal and vertical radiuses. From those coordinates and radiuses, I need to draw an arrow.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SVG you can draw an arrow at the end of a line by using a marker.

In order to know the starting and ending points of the line you need to calculate them as points on the ellipse at a given angle.

Please read the comments in the code.

```js
//object with the first ellipse's attributes
let e1 = { cx: 20, cy: 50, rx: 10, ry: 5 };
//object with the second ellipse's attributes
let e2 = { cx: 120, cy: 20, rx: 10, ry: 5 };
//the distance in x between ellipses
let dx = e2.cx - e1.cx;
//the distance in y between ellipses
let dy = e2.cy - e1.cy;
//the angle
let angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
//the starting point of the line as a point on the first ellipse
let p1 = {
  x: e1.cx + e1.rx * Math.cos(angle),
  y: e1.cy + e1.ry * Math.sin(angle)
};
//the ending point of the line as a point on the second ellipse
let p2 = {
  x: e2.cx + e2.rx * Math.cos(angle + Math.PI),
  y: e2.cy + e2.ry * Math.sin(angle + Math.PI)
};

//setting the attributes of the line
l1.setAttribute("x1", p1.x);
l1.setAttribute("x2", p2.x);
l1.setAttribute("y1", p1.y);
l1.setAttribute("y2", p2.y);
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <marker id="mk" viewBox="0 0 4 4" markerWidth="4" markerHeight="4" refX="4" refY="2" orient="auto">
    <polygon points="0,0 4,2 0,4" />
  </marker>
  <ellipse cx="20" cy="50" rx="10" ry="5" />
  <ellipse cx="120" cy="20" rx="10" ry="5" />

  <line id="l1" stroke="black" marker-end="url(#mk)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: This is great, exactly what I was looking for! I'm surprised the math is so simple. The arrow does _not_ seem to emanate from the center of the origin ellipse, nor does it point to the center of the destination ellipse. Instead, the arrow seems to connect one of the foci of each ellipse. That's actually better for my purpose. Thank you!